# Intel HD graphics 4400 showing up as "Haswell-ULT Integrated graphics controller"

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel

So... I'm trying to figure out why I can't run any of the games I could run easily on Windows. Example 1 Pillars of Destiny 2, it should run fine on my graphics card, but it runs terrible.

Also, I'm curious why I'm not getting OpenGL 4.5 with the newest mesa drivers:

```
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.2.8
```

Also in chrome(or factorio), if I'm in a page with a lot of text, there's diagonal tearing as I scroll down...

Some more info: Running on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Any Thoughts on how to get it to identify the card properly?

Comment: Games optimized for DirectX almost never run as good in OpenGL.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Is there a way to run DirectX on Ubuntu? as far as I understand, that's generally a "No"

Comment: You are getting OpenGL 4.5 or core profiles, Mesa just doesn't give 4.5 Compat profiles.  This isn't a problem for most games.  As far as I can tell the card is being identified just fine.  Is the game a Linux native game, or being run via Wine/Steam Play?  Also try running `sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers` to make sure you have the Vulkan drivers installed.